# JMeter Removes forward slash from start of path parameter

Tags: java, jmeter

I have an endpoint which looks like the following: `www.example.com/example/{resource}`. The resource parameter is normally a uri looking string like this: `/resource/123` which is encoded like this: %2Fresource%2Fid%2F123. The starting forward slash is important, the endpoint does a direct match on something in a database, so it is important.

The issue I am facing is that somewhere between JMeter and the endpoint, the starting forward slash is removed. I tried running the app which has the endpoint locally and when I make the request from PostMan, like this: `GET www.example.com/example/%2Fresource%2F123`, the endpoint decodes it correctly.

In JMeter, I load the resources from a CSV file, which looks like this:

```
resource
/resource/123
/resource/456
/resource/789
```

And in my HTTP Request Config, I use resource like this: `/example/${__urlencode(${resource})}`. The urlencode function doesn't seem to make any different either way.

Whatever I do, when the request is made from JMeter, it doesn't work as expected because the starting hash in resource is removed. I know I could change the endpoint to add a hash if there isn't one but I don't want to change the functionality of the endpoint specifically for JMeter testing.

Any ideas?

### Edit 1

Here is the csv options:

```
<CSVDataSet guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="CSVDataSet" testname="Resource Ids" enabled="true">
   <stringProp name="delimiter">,</stringProp>
   <stringProp name="fileEncoding"></stringProp>
   <stringProp name="filename">data/resource.csv</stringProp>
   <boolProp name="ignoreFirstLine">true</boolProp>
   <boolProp name="quotedData">false</boolProp>
   <boolProp name="recycle">true</boolProp>
   <stringProp name="shareMode">shareMode.group</stringProp>
   <boolProp name="stopThread">false</boolProp>
   <stringProp name="variableNames">resource</stringProp>
</CSVDataSet>
```

Here is the HTML Request Config:

```
<HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="API Request" enabled="true">
    <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
      <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
    </elementProp>
    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">localhost</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">8303</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/example/${__urlencode(${resource})}</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
    <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
    <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
    <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
    <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
</HTTPSamplerProxy>
```

### Edit 2

I have added this pre-processor:

```
<JSR223PreProcessor guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="JSR223PreProcessor" testname="JSR223 PreProcessor" enabled="true">
  <stringProp name="cacheKey">true</stringProp>
  <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
  <stringProp name="parameters"></stringProp>
  <stringProp name="script">vars.put(&quot;resource&quot;, URLEncoder.encode(vars.get(&quot;resource&quot;), &quot;UTF-8&quot;)); </stringProp>
  <stringProp name="scriptLanguage">groovy</stringProp>
</JSR223PreProcessor>
```

### Edit 3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.1.1 r1855137">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group - Test API" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">2</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">0</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration">3600</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay">3600</stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <GenericController guiclass="LogicControllerGui" testclass="GenericController" testname="Get List Items" enabled="true"/>
        <hashTree>
          <CSVDataSet guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="CSVDataSet" testname="Resource Ids" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="delimiter">,</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="fileEncoding"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="filename">data/resource.csv</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="ignoreFirstLine">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="quotedData">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="recycle">true</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="shareMode">shareMode.group</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="stopThread">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="variableNames">resource</stringProp>
          </CSVDataSet>
          <hashTree/>
          <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="Example API Request" enabled="true">
            <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">localhost</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">8303</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/example/${resourceId}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
          </HTTPSamplerProxy>
          <hashTree>
            <JSR223PreProcessor guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="JSR223PreProcessor" testname="JSR223 PreProcessor" enabled="true">
              <stringProp name="cacheKey">true</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
              <stringProp name="parameters"></stringProp>
              <stringProp name="script">vars.put(&quot;resource&quot;, URLEncoder.encode(vars.get(&quot;resource&quot;), &quot;UTF-8&quot;)); </stringProp>
              <stringProp name="scriptLanguage">groovy</stringProp>
            </JSR223PreProcessor>
            <hashTree/>
          </hashTree>
          <ResponseAssertion guiclass="AssertionGui" testclass="ResponseAssertion" testname="Response Assertion" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Asserion.test_strings">
              <stringProp name="49586">200</stringProp>
            </collectionProp>
            <stringProp name="Assertion.custom_message"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Assertion.test_field">Assertion.response_code</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="Assertion.assume_success">false</boolProp>
            <intProp name="Assertion.test_type">8</intProp>
          </ResponseAssertion>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Comment: it should work, can you show how HTTP request and CSV Data Set defined?

Comment: @user7294900 I have added this now.

Comment: in path use `/example${resource}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have only one slash as path separator and not double slash

You have slash in file so in Path remove extra slash:

```
/example${resource}
```

If you want/must URL encode the value you can do it using  [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)

Add it as a **child** to HTTP Request (so it will update value before), code:

```
 vars.put("resource", URLEncoder.encode(vars.get("resource"), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: This isn't working for me because this sends the path parameter as this "resource/123" whilst I need it as this "resource/123". So an unencoded url would like this this: www.example.com/example//resource/123 but this isn't working because jmeter seems to remove one of the double forward slashes

Comment: @Haych see my update (use JSR223 before with update resource variable)

Comment: I have tried this but it still isn't working. I added the config to my answer. Does it look correct to you?

Comment: @Haych it should work if I understand your requirements, are you sure JSR223 is execute before HTTP Request?

Comment: So, I have checked the logs and it is showing that this url is being used: `http://localhost:8303/example/%2FresourceLink%2Fid%2Ff2dfdbf5-e620-47d9-9704-295dc9701c1e`

Which is correct. However, the forward slash still isn't making it to my endpoint.When I use the exact link in Postman, it works (makes it to the endpoint with the starting forward slash).

Comment: I have no headers in either.

Comment: I have added my entire .jmx file. Can you take a look, please? I think that it is purely a JMeter thing.

Comment: @haych there's no JSR223 component with script as in my answer

Comment: Is the JSR223PreProcessor I have not correct? I thought it matched what you meant.

Comment: @Haych did you find the solution? facing the same issue..